# How do you identify the logical data type from a cell array of strings in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, types, cell-array

For example, given the following cell array of strings:

```
C = {'a' '1'; 'b' '2015-08-04'}
```

I would like a function `getCellType` such that `getCellType(C)` returns a cell array like, that is, the "logical" type as interpreted by a human.

```
{'string' 'double'; 'string' 'datetime'}
```

For my current purposes each cell in `C` will only contain scalar values. However, if not obvious, it would be good if answers could touch upon how to identify other non-scalar data like matrices etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply the [`class`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) function on each cell's contents:

```
cellfun(@class, C, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Comment: My apologies. My question example was not correct. In my case I have a cell array of strings, and I want to interpret these strings to return the logical type.